# Can someone help me to understand this python code? Why doesn't this program executes only True statement?

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement, while-loop, do-while

I am a beginner in python programming. This is regarding if condition. I wanted to write a simple program which start the car's engine (*just an imaginary program*). Then I wrote the code below.

According to the program, when I input firstly **start**, it runs True statement **Car started** . Then, when I input **start** secondly, it runs False statement **Car already started**. And then program stopped in the break point. What is my question here is that I want to understand this code how it executes.

Because to my understanding, when I input the first time and then the second time, program should run only the True statement (**Car started**). But when I input the first time, program runs the True statement (**Car started**) and then when I input second time, program runs the False statement **(Car already started)**. Then It breaks the while loop. So, why doesn't program runs the True statement in both times. I want to understand this code.

```
command = ''
started = False
while True:
    command = input('> ').lower()
    if command == 'start':
        if started:
            print('Car already started')
            break
        else:
            started = True
            print('Car started')
```

I tried to understand this code.

Comment: Please write a title relative to YOUR question, not something that could be related to anything

Comment: This is a good opportunity for you to start familiarizing yourself with [using a debugger](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25385173/328193).  When you step through the code in a debugger, which operation first produces an unexpected result?  What were the values used in that operation?  What was the result?  What result was expected?  Why?  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Comment: The second loop program behaves differently because the first loop program sets the "started" variable.

Comment: Did you already forget why you created your `started` variable?

Comment: On the first loop iteration, `started` is false.  But after you enter "start", then `started` becomes true.  That is the difference.

Comment: @KellyBundy How much you want to bet they didn't write the code?

Comment: This code is so simple and straightforward, I do not see how you could have trouble understanding it...

Comment: @Barmar  of course, I am a beginner and I didn't write this code from my head. But I followed one of the tutorials and then I wrote this code. That's what I mentioned above. Anyway, I got clear explanation now. Thank you so much.

Comment: @KellyBundy I am a beginner and I didn't write this code from my head. But I followed one of the tutorials and then I wrote this code. That's what I mentioned above. Anyway, I got clear explanation now. Thank you so much.

Comment: @John Gordon Thank you for the explanation. My head is clear now. Sometimes It is hard to understand simple code also for me.

Comment: _Sometimes It is hard to understand simple code also for me._,  Well, it's a code you claim you wrote.  While it's possible that one may have difficulty debugging a code, it's whole different story to have difficulty understanding it.  Anyways,for a case like this I would suggest to check [Rubber duck debugging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging)

Answer (score 1):

At the first part of the program, you run

```
started = False
```

and so, the first input, it will run the "else" statement because "started" is not equal to True. inside the "else" statement, you make it so "started" is now "True". so, the second input will run the "if" statement and not the "else" statement because the "if" statement is returning "True".